# How to prevent onSelect to fire on already selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I use autosuggestion plugin.

First I have code:

```
$('.auto').autocomplete({

lookup: data,

onSelect: function (suggestion) {

    console.log(koji);
        $('#cena_'+koji).val(suggestion.cena);
        console.log(suggestion.ID);
        $('#jmere'+koji).val(suggestion.jmere);
        $('#kol'+koji).val(suggestion.kol);
        $('#popust'+koji).val(suggestion.popust);
        $('#pdv'+koji).val(suggestion.porez); 
etc...
```

and this is OK, so when I pick some Item from list I update other input fields.

But after that I just choose other value for `#cena or #jmere` but if I click again on input field with class .auto (that is picked before), then onSelect is again fired and values I choose manualy `#cena or #jmere` been changed to suggested values.

Please help me to solve this problem. So how I can prevent call onSelect when there is already picked Item...

The JS code of onSelect is:

```
onSelect: function (index) {
    var that = this,
    onSelectCallback = that.options.onSelect,
    suggestion = that.suggestions[index];

    that.currentValue = that.getValue(suggestion.value);

    if (that.currentValue !== that.el.val() && !that.options.preserveInput) {
        that.el.val(that.currentValue);
    }

    that.signalHint(null);
    that.suggestions = [];
    that.selection = suggestion;

    if ($.isFunction(onSelectCallback)) {
        onSelectCallback.call(that.element, suggestion);
    }
},
```

So is there any way to change onSelect option - to prevent calling when there is already picked some item?

Comment: FYI, `autocomplete` isn't part of jQuery core. I added relevant tag too (if it is really jquery-UI autocomplete you are using...?!)

Comment: try removing the .auto class when items are prezent or unbind the onSelect event

Comment: no I use devbridge autosuggestion plugin, not jquery UI

Comment: how to unbind onselect event?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: I try: $('#usluga376').unbind('onSelect'); but dont work

Comment: I try to remove class auto:         $('#usluga'+koji).removeClass('auto');
 DONT work also $('#usluga376').unbind('onSelect'); dont work

Comment: $('#usluga376').unbind('onSelect'); and onSelect work again. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the autocomplete by using `disable`:

```
$('SELECTOR').autocomplete('disable');
```

And you can change it back like:

```
$('SELECTOR').autocomplete('enable');
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/4o2s8f2g/3/)

If you want to completely remove the autocomplete you can use `despose` ad OP said:

```
$('SELECTOR').autocomplete('dispose');
```

Comment: hm, dont work,maybe is problem becouse I use autoDisabled into ajax success: http://jsfiddle.net/to91udvb/

Comment: look,disable dont excist here: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: make `var autoDisabled = false;` global, if you introduce it in an ajax it's scope will be just that, so the `autoDisabled in the other ajax is just another local.

Comment: I try also: $('#usluga387').autocomplete('disable'); but dont work

Comment: Added a demo to the answer. No don't do like that, it'll be problematic. just make the boolean variable global instead of defining it in Ajax.

Comment: put `var autoDisabled = false; ` above your `function dajjason()`

Comment: I use this: $('#usluga'+koji).autocomplete('dispose'); but thanks very uch for help!

Comment: Thanks, edited the answer for future reference, sorry for the confusion though.